# In welchem Teil Deutschlands sagt man "durchschauen" anstatt "verstehen"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, dialect

> Ich lerne Hochdeutsch, um von der deutschen Gemeinde durchschaut zu werden.
>
> Ich lerne Hochdeutsch, um von der deutschen Gemeinde verstanden zu werden.

In welchem Teil von Deutschland verwendet man *durchschauen* anstatt *verstehen*?

Comment: In keinem, den ich kenne...?

Comment: Deine Beispiele werden so wohl nirgends benutzt. Vielleicht meinst Du so etwas wie z.B.: *Ich blicke/schaue bei diesen vielen Regeln nicht mehr durch.*?

Comment: Jemand ausm Saarland hat "durchschauen" anstatt eines " verstehen" verwendet.

Comment: ***Durchschauen*** and ***verstehen*** have different meanings.

Comment: In welchem Zusammenhang wurde "durchschauen" statt "verstehen" denn benutzt? Ich denke nicht, dass es bei dem oben aufgeführten Beispiel war! Das klingt völlig falsch!

Comment: "Gemeinde" sagt man auch nicht, in diesem Zusammenhang. "Sprachgemeinschaft"

Comment: @userunknown Ich denke hier an Kirchengemeinde... das würde von der Bedeutung her sogar halbwegs passen.

Comment: Hast Du _durchschauen_ eventuell mit dem umgangssprachlichen _durchblicken_ verwechselt?

Comment: @Vogel612: Bei Kirchengemeinden sagt man Gemeinde, wohl wahr, aber "von der deutschen Gemeinde" klingt nun nicht so, als sei von einer Kirchengemeinde die Rede. Sicher - ein Pastor könnte von seinem Umzug reden, aus der französischen in die deutsche Gemeinde - ausgeschlossen ist das nicht.

Answer (score 9):

Der Satz ist so mit Sicherheit von keinem Muttersprachler gesagt worden. Das Wort *durchschauen* passt absolut nicht in dem Kontext.

Das Wort hat im Wesentlichen zwei Bedeutungen. Die erste besagt, dass man die Wahrheit von etwas erkennt.

> Ich durchschaue seinen Plan.
>   Er durchschaute meine Absichten.

Stell dir das so vor, dass du es schaffst, durch einen nicht-transparenten Gegenstand durchzuschauen<sup>1</sup> und dadurch das zu sehen, was sich dahinter verbirgt. Während dies wortwörtlich zu verstehen ist, so ist beispielsweise "einen Plan durchschauen" im figurativen Sinn gemeint. Es werden falsche Tatsachen als Vorwand (entspricht dem nicht-transparenten Gegenstand) vorgegeben, aber du bist sozusagen in der Lage "hindurchzuschauen".

Man kann bei dieser Verwendung auch schon einen Hauch von *verstehen* erkennen. Immerhin hast du den Plan verstanden. Jedoch können in aller Regel die beiden Wörter nicht gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden.

Die zweite Bedeutung von *durchschauen* dagegen ist synonym zu *verstehen*, weil die Definition ist schlicht *verstehen*, *begreifen*, *nachvollziehen*.

> Ich durchschaue[=verstehe] die Spielregeln nicht.

Hier geht es lediglich um das Verständnis einer Sache, die möglicherweise komplex ist, aber nicht die Intention hat, dich in die Irre zu führen oder etwas von dir zu verheimlichen.

Zurück zu deinem Beispiel: Dort geht es um eine ganz andere Sache, nämlich um das Verstehen von Wörtern und ihrer Bedeutung im Zusammenhang. Also den Sinn erfassen. Dies kann mit *durchschauen* nicht ausgedrückt werden.

---

<sup>1</sup> Achtung: *Durchschauen* im Sinne von *hindurchgucken* ist ein anderes Wort.

Comment: Ja der Sinn hindruchgucken kam hier nicht in Frage, aber der wäre mir auch gar nicht in den Sinn gekommen, dafür ein **dickes** +!

Comment: Ich bin nicht überzeugt, dass *durchschauen* wirklich zwei unterschiedliche Bedeutungen hat. Im Beispiel mit den Spielregeln wird mMn angedeutet, dass diese derart komplex sind, dass sie sich sozusagen aktiv dem Verständnis widersetzen (und somit wiederum dem nicht-transparenten Gegenstand entsprechen).

Answer (score 7):

Deine Frage bezog sich zwar ausdrücklich auf Deutschland, aber wenn ich die Intention der Frage richtig deute, meinst du vermutlich den deutschen Sprachraum bzw. das deutsche Sprachgebiet. Von den knapp 100 Millionen deutschen Muttersprachlern leben nämlich nur ca. 82 Millionen in Deutschland, während auch in Österreich, in der Schweiz, in Liechtenstein, in Italien, in Belgien und in Luxemburg mehr als 15 Millionen Menschen leben, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Keines dieser Länder gehört zu Deutschland, und kaum jemand, der in einem dieser Länder lebt, fühlt sich als Deutscher.

In diesem Sinne erlaube ich mir, die Frage für Österreich (vor allem für den Osten des Landes) zu beantworten:

> Ich verstehe dich.

Das kann heißen:

- Ich kann deine Motivation nachvollziehen, ich begreife also, warum jemand, der in deiner Situation ist, das tut, was du getan hast:

  > Du hättest ihn ja nicht gleich erschießen müssen. Aber nach allem was er dir angetan hat, verstehe ich, dass du so gehandelt hast.
- Ich höre deine Worte und kann ihnen Sinn entnehmen:

  > Vorhin klang deine Stimme durch's Telefon so abgehackt, aber jetzt ist es besser. Jetzt verstehe ich dich.
- Ich kann den Ausführungen meines Gesprächspartners folgen:

  > A: Egon war als Letzter im Zimmer und er war auch derjenige, der dort alles abgewischt hat, was sonst nicht so seine Art ist. Und von allen Verdächtigen hatte er auch das stärkste Motiv. Verstehst du, was ich damit sagen will?
  >   B: Ja, ich verstehe dich.

> Ich durchschaue dich.

Diese Formulierung verwendet man eher, wenn jemand eigentlich seine Motive verbergen will, man sie aber trotzdem erkennen kann. Das hat eher etwas mit einer begründeten Vermutung zu tun.

> Glaube nur nicht, dass ich nicht weiß, warum du jeden zweiten Tag zum Hof vom Ortner gehst. Seine Tocher, die Resi, hat nicht nur schöne Augen. Ich durchschaue dich, du Hallodri!

**Analyse deiner Beispielsätze**

> Ich lerne Hochdeutsch, um von der deutschen Gemeinde verstanden zu werden.

Hier verwendest du »*verstehen*« im Sinn von »*jemanden hören und den Worten dabei Sinn entnehmen können*«. Du lernst eine Sprache mit dem Ziel, dass diejenigen, die diese Sprache schon gut beherrschen, aus dem was du sagst rekonstruieren können, was du damit meinst.

Das ist eine völlig korrekte und auch übliche Verwendung von »verstehen«.

> Ich lerne Hochdeutsch, um von der deutschen Gemeinde durchschaut zu werden.

Zumindest in Österreich wird dieser Satz als falsch empfunden. Grammatisch ist er zwar richtig, aber er sagt folgendes aus:

Du lernst eine Sprache, damit die Sprecher dieser Sprache in die Lage versetzt werden, deine Beweggründe, die dich zu einer hier nicht näher beschriebenen Tat motivieren und die du eigentlich verheimlichen willst, erkennen können. Das ist ein Widerspruch. Du versuchst etwas zu verbergen und unternimmst gleichzeitig etwas, damit andere das offenlegen können, was du zu verbergen suchst.

Dieser logische Widerspruch verbietet zumindest in Österreich die Verwendung von »durchschauen« in diesem Satz.

Wie die Situation in anderen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums ist, darüber kann ich nur spekulieren. Meine Vermutung: Es ist in diesem Fall überall so wie in Österreich. Aber ich weiß das nicht mit Bestimmtheit.

Comment: Und was du für Österreich schreibst, würde ich so auch genau für Deutschland, inklusive Saarland, unterschreiben.

Comment: @Iris »Das Saarland und das Reich«? ;)

Comment: An dieser Stelle möchte ich bei allen, die das machen, mal für das Korrigieren meiner Antworten (vor allem der englischen) bedanken. Wenn ich selber die eigenen Fehler bemerken würde, würde ich sie erst gar nicht machen.

Answer (score 0):

Die Krux liegt in den verschiedenen Bedeutungen von *verstehen* und *durchschauen.* Hubert hat sich in seiner Antwort vor Allem auf die Bedeutungen von *verstehen* konzentriert, Em1 diejenigen von *durchschauen* analysiert.

In einem Spezialfall sind beide Wörter synonym, oder werden zumindest im Südosten Deutschlands als solche verwendet:

> Ich habe das mathematische Konzept verstanden.
>
> Ich habe das mathematische Konzept durchschaut.

Selbst in diesem Sonderfall ist allerdings noch eine Bedeutungsnuance zwischen beiden vorhanden.

In allen anderen Fällen sind die beiden Wörter so unterschiedlich, dass man sie nicht synonym verwenden kann und dass das Ersetzen des Einen durch das Andere entweder zu einem unidiomatischen Satz oder aber zu einer deutlichen Bedeutungsverschiebung führt.