# Komma in „aus dem, was du sagst“

Tags: punctuation, comma

In einer [Antwort von heute](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27062/1224) heißt es:

> Du lernst eine Sprache, mit dem Ziel, dass diejenigen, die diese Sprache schon gut beherrschen, **aus dem was du sagst rekonstruieren können**, was du damit meinst.

In diesem Satz wollte ich Kommata korrigieren. Bei dem von mir hervorgehobenen Abschnitt bin ich mir jedoch nicht sicher, ob das so richtig ist oder ob da zwei Kommata hinkommen.

„Was du sagst“ ist prinzipiell erstmal ein Relativsatz. Beispielsweise vollkommen natürlich für mich:

> Aus dem, was du sagst, entnehme ich, dass …

Irgendwie habe ich aber das Gefühl, dass in dem Satz oben das dann sogar fürs Deutsche zu viele Kommata sind. Ich würde fast hingehen und „aus dem was du sagst“ als kompakte Phrase ansehen. Mir fehlt hier grade eine korrekter Terminus dafür, aber was ich andeuten will, ist, dass „was du sagst“ hier möglicherweise nicht ein Relativsatz ist, auch wenn es so aussieht.
Ähnlich zu beispielsweise meinem Satz von oben: „Bei dem von mir hervorgehobenen Abschnitt“. Nur ist dort es eine Mischung von Präpositionalphrase und einer Nominalphrase und daher nicht wirklich vergleichbar.

Eine kurze Internetsuche zeigt auf jeden Fall auf, dass ein Komma hier besonders häufig ausgelassen wird. Auch wenn Kommafehler im Deutschen eh gang und gäbe sind, heißt das, dass sich hier viele intuitiv gegen das Komma entscheiden und dass ich wohl nicht der Einzige bin, der sich hier unsicher ist.

Also entspricht es einem Relativsatz oder ist es eine Phrase (welche Art Phrase?), wo das *was* eben keinen Relativsatz einleitet? Oder funktioniert es hier als Zusatz, Apposition, und *kann*, muss aber nicht, durch ein Komma getrennt werden?

Comment: Related: [Komma oder kein Komma in „Du weißt was das bedeutet?“](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25953/9551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> § 74 Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigen Komma ein.
>
> § 76 Bei formelhaften Nebensätzen kann man das Komma weglassen.

Dementsprechend ist die eine Interpretation, dass »was du sagst« ein Nebensatz ist, der mit paarigen Kommas abgegrenzt werden muss, richtig.

Ob und inwiefern die drei Wörter auch als »formelhafter Nebensatz« aufgefasst werden können, weiß ich nicht genau, und liegt im Zweifel im Ermessen des Schreibenden. Die amtlichen Beispiele sind »wie bereits gesagt« und »wenn nötig«, und zeichnen sich dadurch aus, dass sie kein finites Verb enthalten. Die Rechtschreibregeln schweigen sich aus, ob das Fehlen eines finiten Verbs die Formelhaftigkeit der Nebensätze ausmacht oder ob andere Bedingungen zu erfüllen sind.

Persönlich würde ich die Kommas auf jeden Fall setzen.

Comment: Also müsste man die Frage stellen: Was macht einen Nebensatz formelhaft?