# Was zeichnet einen Satz als "formelhaft" aus?

Tags: terminology

In einer [Antwort zu einer Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27070/komma-in-aus-dem-was-du-sagst/27075#27075) vor einigen Tagen ist von "formelhaften Nebensätzen" die Rede.

Die prompte Frage, die sich daraus ergab, war: Was macht einen Satz formelhaft?

Es gibt eine Vielzahl an Beispielen, die denke ich recht offensichtlich unter den Begriff "formelhafter Nebensatz" fallen. Andere sind es weniger. Wie kann ich nun aber entscheiden, ob eine Phrase zu diesen gehört oder nicht?

Die Beispiele aus den Rechtschreibregeln lauten:

- wenn nötig
- wie bereits gesagt

Weitere Beispiele, aus einem [Beitrag aus Canoonet's Blog](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2014/06/30/ein-satz-mit-weiss-ich-wie-vielen-kommas/):

- wer weiß wie oft
- weiß ich wie lange
- weiß Gott

Es fällt natürlich auf, dass dies alles recht gängige Floskeln sind, die darüber hinaus kurz und bündig sind. Aber wird damit jede kurze Floskel zum formelhaften Satz? Oder gar jede Floskel? Oder gar jeder kurze Satz?

Eine Google-Suche nach "formelhafter Nebensatz" bringt zwar viele Ergebnisse und endlose Beispiele, aber keine einzige Definition. Auch aus gezielten Suchen auf renommierten Seiten wie [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/) oder [Grammis vom Institut für deutsche Sprache](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/) habe ich keine näheren Kriterien beziehen können.

Also: Was sind die Bedingungen, damit ich einen Nebensatz als formelhaft bezeichnen darf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Buch "Perfektes Deutsch - Der Ratgeber in sprachlichen Zweifelsfällen" heißt es im [Abschnitt 75](https://books.google.de/books?id=F8oNBvGlqx4C&pg=PP1&dq=Perfektes%20Deutsch%20Ratgeber%20in%20sprachlichen%20Zweifelsf%C3%A4llen&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicx-7cutvJAhVCdQ8KHZFjDDEQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=formelhaften%20Nebens%C3%A4tze&f=false) (Das Komma bei Satzellipsen):

> Eine Reihe von Nebensätzen, die zu Satzellipsen verkürzt worden sind, werden fast nur noch in dieser Kurzform verwendet. Diese sogenannten **formelhaften Nebensätze** werden nicht durch Komma abgetrennt.
>
> Solche formelhaften Auslassungssätze sind vor allem **unvollständige Nebensätze**, deren Vollform mit den Konjunktionen **wie**, **wenn** oder **falls** eingeleitet wird. Man fasst diese Verkürzungen meist als **einfache adverbiale Bestimmungen** auf, die als Satzglied in den Satz einbezogen sind und trennt sie **nicht durch Komma** ab. Das **Komma kann** allerdings gesetzt werden.

Als Beispiel dort gelistet:

> ..., wie ich es schon angedeutet habe, ...
> ... wie schon angedeutet ...
>
> Falls es erforderlich ist, ...
> Falls erforderlich ...

Im Weiteren heißt es dann noch, dass auch Sätze, die mit **wo** eingeleitet sind, zumeist als formelhaft angesehen werden.

Unter dem Aspekt wären die in der Frage genannten Beispiele *wer weiß wie oft*, *weiß ich wie lange* und *weiß Gott* keine formelhaften Nebensätze. Trotzdem sind es eindeutig adverbiale Bestimmung. Daher mag die Definition oben wahrscheinlich noch nicht vollständig sein.

Bei diesen Sätzen scheint es sich aber vielmehr eigentlich um sogenannte *Schaltsätze* zu handeln. Dies sind Sätze, die in einen anderen eingeschoben werden, ohne dass eine grammatische Beziehung vorliegt.
Diese werden für gewöhnlich durch ein Komma abgetrennt. Es bleibt also noch offen, ob und wann ein Schaltsatz als formelhaftig angesehen werden kann. Nach Wahrig's "Richtiges Deutsch leicht gemacht" können aber [Schaltsätze definitiv formelhaft](https://books.google.de/books?id=sZGwuIt2FEMC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=schaltsatz%20formelhaft&source=bl&ots=kioJLaS9tk&sig=Nv7nSMrMbOjFY-_Gt6D19PmZ4Ok&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjoluWov9vJAhVFKg8KHZNXCd8Q6AEIFDAA#v=onepage&q=formelhafter%20Schaltsatz&f=false) sein.

> Formelhaft gebrauchte Schaltsätze werden ohne Komma in den Satzverlauf einbezogen.
>
> > Das habe ich dir schon wer weiß wie oft gesagt.
> > Er ist sonst weiß Gott nicht ängstlich.

Festhalten kann man aber: Verkürzte Nebensätze (Ellipsen), die mit *wie*, *wenn*, *falls* oder *wo* eingeleitet sind, stellen einen formelhaften Nebensatz dar.